# How to partially seed files on qBitTorrent?

Tags: bittorrent

I'm downloading a 80 gigabyte file and I've downloaded 30 gigabytes. I've decided I don't want the file but I'm on a private tracker so I have to maintain a ratio of 1.0. How do I seed the 30 gigabytes I have without downloading more? On Deluge, I can just select "Do not download" on the file and it will just seed.

Comment: Are you sure the private tracker counts partially seeded torrents against your ratio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right click on the file entry in the top window, select "Limit download rate", and set it to 1 KiB/s (just hit the up arrow next to the infinity symbol once). Can't stop the download completely, but that's slow enough to effectively stop it.

Comment: Looks like this is the closest I'm going to get. There's an issue open: https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/issues/3992